# Prove that the square root measurement $\Lambda_y=\frac14(\rho_{B^3})^{-\frac12}|\psi_y\rangle\langle\psi_y|(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is a POVM

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, povm

Consider $\textit{X}\sim \mathrm{Unif}([0,1,2,3]), |\mathcal{Y}|=|\mathcal{X}|=4$. Also for every random variable realization {\it x} we use three parallel quantum channels like the one employed before such that:

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \rho_{XB^{3}}=\sum_{x}p_{X}(x)|x\rangle\langle x|_{X}\otimes|\psi_{x}\rangle\langle\psi_{x}|_{B^{3}},
\end{equation}

Prove that the Square Root Measurement:
$$ \Lambda_{y}=\frac{1}{4}(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}|\psi_{y}\rangle\langle\psi_{y}|(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}},$$  for $ y\in[0,1,2,3], $

is a positive operator-valued measure.

A positive operator-valued measure (POVM) is a set of operators $\{\Lambda_j\}$ that satify:
\begin{align*}
     \Lambda_j&\succeq 0\\
     \sum_j \Lambda_j &=I. 
\end{align*}

I have proved the first property (I think):

For any state $|\phi\rangle$, we need to prove that  $\langle \phi | \Lambda | \phi \rangle \geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\langle \phi | \Lambda_{y} | \phi \rangle &= \frac{1}{4} \langle \phi | (\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}|\psi_{y}\rangle\langle\psi_{y}|(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}} | \phi \rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{4}  | (\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}|\phi \rangle |^2 \\
&\geq 0
\end{align*}

I am having trouble to prove the second property:

I have to prove the following equality:
$$\sum_{y} \langle \phi | \Lambda_{y} | \phi \rangle = \langle \phi | \phi \rangle$$

For that what I have is:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{y} \langle \phi | \Lambda_{y} | \phi \rangle &= \sum_{y} \frac{1}{4} \langle \phi | (\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}|\psi_{y}\rangle\langle\psi_{y}|(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}} | \phi \rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \langle \phi | (\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_{y} |\psi_{y}\rangle\langle\psi_{y}|\right)(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}} | \phi \rangle \\
\end{align*}

But I don't know how to follow.

Comment: Well, how do you define $\rho_B$?

Comment: @Rammus I edited the question.

Comment: what are $|\psi_y\rangle$, $\rho_{B^3}$, $|\theta_x\rangle$? Also, is this taken from some textbook? You mention quantum channels "used before" but never define them. Please link all relevant sources.

Comment: My comment was more to help you answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all people in the comments section that have helped me to arrive to this conclusion:

\begin{align*}
    \sum_y \Lambda_y 
    &= \sum_y \frac{1}{4}(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}|\psi_{y}\rangle\langle\psi_{y}|(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
    &=(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_y \left(\frac{1}{4}|\psi_{y}\rangle\langle\psi_{y}|\right)(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
    &=(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\rho_{B^3}(\rho_{B^{3}})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
    &=I
\end{align*}

Where we have used that $X\sim \mathrm{Unif}([0,1,2,3])$, so the probabilities in the spectral decomposition are $\frac{1}{4}.$